# Android memory: how to inspect memory without using Profiler?

Tags: java, android, profiler, android-memory, android-profiler

I have a problem of OOM error (OutOfMemory) with my app. It seems that it is due to an object that takes more and more room in memory but I don't manage to find which one.

I would like to use the Android Profiler to find the problem. But I have a real time app that uses a lot the device processor and memory, and when I use the Profiler the app becomes really slow and becomes almost impossible to use (I need to use the app at least 3 minutes at normal speed in order to see the memory growing progressively).

My questions are:

- is there a way to use the Profiler without this slowdown issue?
- if not, are there any other tools or methodology in order to help me finding which object grows in memory?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can collect your app's heapdump using `adb shell`

```
adb shell am dumpheap <PID> <TARGET_FILE>
```

and view the exported file using [android studio profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#import-hprof)

Alternatively, if you know when exactly in your app the OOM happens, you can collect the heapdump using [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug#dumpHprofData(java.lang.String)) `Debug.dumpHprofData(String)`

Comment: Thanks. I do 'adb shell am dumpheap ...' but I get 'Unable to open file: dump.hprof
Consider using a file under /data/local/tmp/'. Should I create a empty dump.hprof on my phone at this location? Other solution? May I create the file directly on my Mac?

Comment: if you cannot run this command as su (if your phone is not rooted), you can leave the just not specifying a <TARGET_FILE> and leave it empty, `am` will name the file itself and print it for you